# SQL Server - Delete Duplicate Rows - how does Partition By affect this query?

Tags: sql-server

I've been using the following inherited query where I'm trying to delete duplicate rows and I'm getting some unexpected results when first running it as a SELECT - I believe it has something to do with my lack of understanding of the Partition part of the statement:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [Id],
    [Url],
    [Identifier], 
    [Name], 
    [Entity], 
    [DOB],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name)
   FROM Data.Statistics
   where Id = 2170
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Can someone help me understand exactly what I'm doing with the Partition BY Name part of this?  This doesn't limit the query in any way to only looking for duplicates in the Name field, correct?  I need to ensure that it's looking for records where ***all 5*** of the fields inside the CTE definition are the same for a record to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Then you need to add all 5 to the `partition by` because your current query only checks for duplicate `name`. If you want a preview just change `delete` to `select`.

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim.  I knew about running it as SELECT - this is what I meant by strange results.  I've edited my post to be more clear about that.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: It might help to think of "partition by" as being similar to "group by" - you get different sets of row numbers for each group of columns you partition by.

Comment: This makes sense @ZLK thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name)` doesn't make a lot of sense.  You wouldn't `ORDER BY` the same thing you used in `PARTITION BY` since it will be the same value for everything in the partition, making the `ORDER BY` part useless.

Basically the CTE part of this query is saying to split the matching rows (those with [Id] = 2170) temporarily into groups for each distinct name, and within each group of rows with the same name, order those by name (which are obviously all the same value) and then return the row number within that sequence group as `RN`.  Unique names will all have a row number of 1, because there is only one row with that name.  Duplicate names will have row numbers 1, 2, 3, and so on.  The order of those rows is undefined in this case because of the silly `ORDER BY` clause, but if you changed the `ORDER BY` to something meaningful, the row numbers would follow that sequence.

Comment: Tim. very well-worded and easy to understand.  Thank you for that.  I've marked it as the answer.

Comment: Hey @Tim one follow-up question - could you give me an example of something that could be used in place of ORDER BY to be more meaningful?

Comment: If for example, you had a record created date and you wanted to keep the oldest record and delete the newer duplicate records you would use `ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CreationDate)` which would assign the oldest record for the name row number 1, and the next oldest would be row 2, etc.  The outer query deletes all but row 1.